# Conditional statements wiith boolean logic when calculating metrics in Tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api

As a Tableau newbie I have what I imagine is a very basic question-

I am trying to create a calculated metric called "AppointmentVolume".  I would like to just do a countd on an attribute called `ConfirmationNumber` (dimension) where another dimension, "IsCancelled" is 'false'.  Both attributes are in the same table

I have tried a number of different statements, and all show up as 'invalid'

I thought it would be something like:

```
countd(ConfirmationNumber) WHERE (IsCancelled='False')
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated- its driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to put your conditional statement inside the aggregate like this:

```
COUNTD(IF IsCancelled = 'False' THEN ConfirmationNumber END)
```